# Ratio of two positive functions

Tags: functions

Let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be two nonnegative functions over $[0,a]$ with
$g(0)=h(0)=0$,
$$
g'(x)\leq h'(x),
$$
and $g(x)>0$ and $h(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,a)$.
Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}
$$
over $(0,a)$
with
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1.
$$
(An example is $g(x)=\sin 2x$ and $h(x)=2\sin x$ for $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$.)
Is it true that $f(x)$ is non-increasing over $(0,a)$ (since $g(x)$ does not "grow" faster than $h(x)$)?

Comment: $f(x)$ is strictly increasing precisely when $h(x)g'(x) > g(x)h'(x)$ by the quotient rule, and this is certainly possible even if $g'(x) \le h'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $g,h\colon(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
h(x)=x, \qquad g(x)=(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))) x
$$
so that (1) $f,g\geq 0$, (2) $\lim_{x\to 0^+} h(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x)=0$, (3) $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = 1$, (4) $g'(x) \leq h'(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,1]$.

However,
$$
\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{1}{1-\sin(x)\cos(x)}
$$
which is not monotone on $(0,1]$.

[image]

Comment: At a high level (and ignoring for now the constraints $g(0)=h(0)=0$ and $h(x)\sim g(x)$ at $0$), you have one condition $g'\leq h'$, and ask if that implies $(\log g)' \leq (\log h)'$. It does not.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Take $g(x)=x^2-\exp(-1/x)$, $h(x)=x^2$ and $a=1$. (Note that $g$ can be defined in $x=0$ by putting $g(0):=0$.)